# RAID 1 vs RAID 0 with Seagate Ironwolf

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas, synology, qnap

I am about to buy a NAS server from Synology or QNAP, it's supposed to be used for Plex Media Server.

I'll buy some Seagate Ironwolf NAS HDD Drivers, but I am wondering if I have to setup like RAID 1 or RAID 0. I want to have 8 TB and using RAID 0 would be half of the price, but not sure about failures in such devices the NAS and the HDD as well.

Please, provide me some thoughts to consider one or another option or discard any of them.

Answer (score 1):

RAID0 has 0 redundancy. It makes a single disk.
RAID1 has a copy of all the data on each disk.

If its just rips or copies of data.you can easily reaquire, RAID0 is cheap and slightly faster then JBOD or a single large disk.  If you need reliability, RAID1 is the minimum.

Hard drives fail - a lot. You are playing a loosing game of you dont have backups - ideally off-site and offline. Seagate ironwolfs have spinning platters. Mechanical stuff wears out and dies - not always predictably.